# Not possible to add child nodes to sprite for CCProgressTimer?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to add child nodes to sprite and then use `CCProgressTimer` to gradually reveal it. But the child node, in my case `CCLabelTTF` is not appearing on screen at all. I can only see the `testSprite`.

```
CCSprite *testSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"btnsmall-red-normal.png"];
CCLabelTTF *labeltest = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Testing123" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64];
[labeltest setPosition:ccpMult( ccpFromSize(testSprite.contentSize), 0.5f )];
[testSprite addChild: labeltest];
CCProgressTimer *testPT = [CCProgressTimer progressWithSprite:testSprite];
[self addChild:testPT];
testPT.position = ccp(windowSize.width/2, windowSize.height/2+100);
testPT.percentage = 100;
```

Comment: did u try by changing the position to 0,0 just for test.

Comment: Yes, changing label position to `0,0` doesn't help. Still the label is not rendered. Is this some limitation?

Comment: hmmm i dont think so. if u simply add to node instead of Progress Timer does it work?

Comment: If I add `testSprite` object to scene, without `CCProgressTimer` I can see both sprite and label.

Comment: i think that some thing with Label need to dig. But solution is i think if u can get the texture from label and convert that to sprite too then it will work.

Comment: and I think this is some limitation. From `CCProgressTimer` it appears that it is working only with texture of sprite. Hope someone can shed some light on this class.